# Diagonalising the form by completing the square

Tags: linear-algebra

Write down the matrix A associated to the quadratic form
$$3x^2 + 3y^2+3z^2-2xy-2xz-2yz$$
Classify the form as positive/negative definite/semidefinite,
or indefinite.
Diagonalise the form by completing the square.

I've worked out the matrix which is:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 3 & -1 \\
    -1 & -1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

How would I then complete the square to diagoanlise the form?

Any help is much appreciated :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's quite simple:$$3x^2 + 3y^2+3z^2-2xy-2xz-2yz=(-x+y+z)^2+(x-y+z)^2+(x+y-z)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

There is the intuitive leap as in the other answer, but if you want a systematic method there is the beginning. 
$$3x^2 + 3y^2+3z^2-2xy-2xz-2yz$$
collect all $x$ terms
$$=3(x^2 -\frac{2}{3}x(y+z))+ 3y^2+3z^2-2yz$$
complete the square
$$=3(x^2 -\frac{2}{3}x(y+z)+\frac{(y+z)^2}{9}) -\frac{(y+z)^2}{3}+ 3y^2+3z^2-2yz$$
$$=3(x -\frac{1}{3}(y+z))^2-\frac{(y+z)^2}{3}+ 3y^2+3z^2-2yz$$
now factor the $y,z$ terms.

Comment: Hi sorry, just going back to this again. Should it not be x in the last line of working as opposed to x^2?

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

...............